# How to draw a double rotating arrow in a matrix of nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

**I am trying to draw a double 90 degree rotating arrow that connect two nodes in a tikz matrix**

**Here is what I would like to do:**

[image]

However I am not sure how to approach a problem like this.

I tried creating a matrix of nodes which contain nodes that are not drawn.

Thus in the example above the node called A would need to be connected to an invisible node called a. Then a line would need to be drawn between the two invisible nodes. Thus a to b. Lastly a line would be drawn from b to B.

**Here is my question:**

## What is the best and simplest way to create a double rotating arrow?

**From my understanding there is three ways to create a double rotating arrow between two nodes in a tikz matrix**

1. Create a matrix with a row with invisible nodes. Then connect the nodes with lines.
2. Use the calc package to find the right coordinates to connect. (not sure how to do this).
3. Use a scope with chains. (Also don't know how to do this.)

**Here is my code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                shadows}     


% My tikz picture

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix(a)[matrix of nodes , nodes in empty cells,
nodes = {font = \small , rectangle , align = center , text width = 2cm , minimum size = 1cm},
row sep = {2cm , between origins} , 
column sep = {4cm , between origins}]{
% Matrix begins here.
& |[draw]|Documents  &  & \\
& &  & \\
|[draw]| Directory document    &    |[draw]| Water document   & |[draw]| Data document\\
};


%%%%%Draw arrow lines;


\draw[-{Stealth[length=4mm]}] (a-1-2) -- (a-3-2);

\draw (a-2-2) -- (a-2-3);

\draw [-{Stealth[length=4mm]}](a-2-3) -- (a-3-3);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

**My output is:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to repair your code, you could draw the arrows from the centre of the node instead of the edge:

```
\draw (a-2-2.center) -- (a-2-3.center);
\draw [-{Stealth[length=4mm]}](a-2-3.center) -- (a-3-3);
```

To make things easier, you could use the `|-|` path operator from the `ext.paths.ortho` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {Documents};
\node[draw,below right=of a] (b) {Data};

\draw[->] (a) |-| (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]